# ¿"Impeachment" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, lenguaje-jurídico

Estos días se [leo](http://v) con frecuencia la palabra **impeachment** para explicar el proceso de destitución de la presidenta del gobierno de Brasil, Dilma Rousseff.

En muchas noticias en castellano utilizan esta palabra para designar, citando la [Wikipedia en castellano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment).

> ... una figura del Derecho anglosajón (específicamente en Estados
>   Unidos y Gran Bretaña) mediante el cual se puede procesar a un alto
>   cargo público.

Al ser una figura del derecho anglosajón entiendo que haya problemas para encontrar una traducción exacta. Por ello, continúa el artículo diciendo que:

> Las traducciones al español más comunes son "moción de censura",
>   "impugnación", "impedimento", o "acusación pública" (también se usa
>   "juicio político").

De entre estas opciones, *moción de censura* no me parece que contenga todo el significado pues no tiene porqué ser debido a cuestiones jurídicas.

Así que aprovechando que en este sitio hay gente con ambas lenguas maternas, me pregunto: ¿hay alguna forma especialmente indicada para traducir esta figura jurídica?

Comment: Iba a ver la palabra que utilizan en portugués para ver si podríamos traducir esa al castellano.  Pero resulta que usan simplemente la palabra inglesa tal cual, tanto en Brasil como en Portugal.  =/

Comment: @guifa exacto. Incluso en castellano de España es lo más frecuente. Siempre se habla del *impeachment a Nixon*, por ejemplo.

Comment: en España, se puede entender, ya que no hay equivalente (y el proceso es tan infrecuente en los países en que hay que existiendo una traducción, sería poco conocida).  Pero uno pensaría que al adoptarlo, intentarían los brasileños alguna traducción lógica como hizo Méjico.

Comment: @guifa supongo que es de esos casos en el que el primero en utilizarlo en el caso Dilma pudo "bautizar" la palabra en nuestro idioma, pues seguramente el resto de periodistas habrían usado el mismo vocablo. Al usar *impeachment*, parece que el anglicismo va a resistir durante unos años más.

Comment: FYI Although impeach has been used in the English language since the 14th century, it has not always been restricted to the commonly used modern sense of "to charge (a public official) with a crime done while in office"; other meanings over the years have included....  continue reading here http://www.merriam-webster.com/trend-watch/impeach-2016-04-18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por dejarlo aquí reflejado, la Fundéu tiene publicado [un artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/proceso-de-destitucion-impeachment/) en el que expone:

> Las expresiones ***proceso de destitución* y *procedimiento de destitución*** son apropiadas para referirse al procedimiento **conocido en inglés como *impeachment***.

Y añade más adelante:

> El anglicismo *impeachment* designa el procedimiento, característico de algunos sistemas políticos, por el que **un órgano legislativo procesa a un alto cargo para una eventual destitución**.
>
> Con este sentido pueden emplearse en español las expresiones *proceso de destitución* y *procedimiento de destitución* o, en función del ordenamiento jurídico de cada país, otras como ***juicio político*, *juicio de desafuero* o *proceso político***.

Y concluye:

> De optarse por la palabra inglesa, se recomienda escribirla en cursiva o, en su defecto, entre comillas.

Comment: Sí, la RAE últimamente se ha manifestado en este sentido, tal y como se recoge en el artículo [Traducir o no traducir ‘impeachment’, esa es la cuestión (lingüística)](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2019/09/26/articulo/1569491832_282249.html)

Answer (score 8):

En México se utiliza el término ***juicio político*** de manera oficial, definido como tal en la constitución política del país. La cámara de diputados del gobierno mexicano emite información acerca de las asambleas celebradas con regularidad en el congreso, así como información relevante referente a las leyes estipuladas en la constitución política; La información emitida es archivada física y virtualmente para que pueda ser utilizada por los ciudadanos con el fin de promover la transparencia de información del gobierno. En una búsqueda realizada en la biblioteca virtual de la cámara de diputados, me encuentro con una amplia definición del término en cuestión y sobre todo, una parte del texto donde especifica su origen, el cual es atribuido directamente al término inglés *impeachment*, originario de la Gran Bretaña. Cito textualmente la información mas relevante del [documento](http://archivos.diputados.gob.mx/Centros_Estudio/cedip/PUBLICACIONES/EXPEDIENTE_PARLAMENTARIO/14/14.pdf):

> En esencia, el juicio político es una institución de interés general
>   establecido en las leyes fundamentales de la mayoría de los países del
>   mundo. Su origen se halla en el procedimiento al Rey Carlos I, seguido
>   por la Cámara de los Comunes del Parlamento Inglés, organismo
>   legislativo que, personificando a la soberanía popular, sentenció al
>   soberano a pena de muerte, acusado de tirano, traidor, asesino y
>   enemigo del país.  En ese caso, con una votación unánime, se dictó
>   resolución, en un procedimiento que, en la parte occidental del mundo,
>   se considera históricamente como el primer enjuiciamiento político o
>   impeachment instruido a un gobernante.

Comment: En Argentina también se usa *juicio político*, aunque no es llamado así en la Constitución.

Answer (score 0):

Revocación de mandato, es una figura jurídica.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Recomiendo revisar las secciones de [tour] y [help] (no se tarda nada) para parender un poco más sobre la filosofía de este sitio. Esta respuesta ganaría mucho si explicases un poco más. Qué es una "revocación de mandato" y por qué piensas que es la mejor traducción para "impeachment". Tal como está la respuesta, hay que hacer un poco de investigación para entneder realmente qué estas diciendo y si es válido en este contexto.